# JAX-WS WebService, Addressing, MTOM and RespectBinding Features Use Cases

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am learning web services in Java. I would like to know the uses for the  following 4 classes with the help of a very simple use case - WebServiceFeature, AddressingFeature, MTOMFeature, RespectBindingFeature. 

Suppose, I am publishing a web service which will list all States in the United States. How would I utilize these 4 classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) Version 2.1 introduced the concept of features as a way to programmatically control specific functions and behaviors.

WebServiceFeature as per [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature.html)

> A WebServiceFeature is used to represent a feature that can be enabled or disabled for a web service.
>
> The JAX-WS specification will define some standard features and JAX-WS implementors are free to define additional features if necessary. Vendor specific features may not be portable so caution should be used when using them.

AddressingFeature as per [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/AddressingFeature.html)

> AddressingFeature represents the use of WS-Addressing with either the SOAP 1.1/HTTP or SOAP 1.2/HTTP binding. Using this feature with any other binding is undefined.
>
> This feature can be used during the creation of SEI proxy, and Dispatch instances on the client side and Endpoint instances on the server side. This feature cannot be used for Service instance creation on the client side.

MTOMFeature as per [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/MTOM.html)

> This feature represents the use of MTOM with a web service.

Also

> JAX-WS supports the use of SOAP Message Transmission Optimized Mechanism (MTOM) for sending binary attachment data. By enabling MTOM, you can send and receive binary data optimally without incurring the cost of data encoding needed to embed the binary data in an XML document.

RespectBindingFeature as per [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/RespectBindingFeature.html)

> This feature clarifies the use of the wsdl:binding in a JAX-WS runtime. This feature can be used during the creation of SEI proxy, and Dispatch instances on the client side and Endpoint instances on the server side. This feature cannot be used for Service instance creation on the client side.
>
> This feature is only useful with web services that have an associated WSDL.

**Use Cases** - unfortunately, see the Java Docs - I only say unfortunately as with me developing web services for several years now - I've never needed to use "WebServiceFeature,AddressingFeature, MTOMFeature, RespectBindingFeature" - they're for niche use cases which I dont believe most developers need to deal with.  The most beneficial one I see would be the MTOMFeature but if you simply want a web service that lists all of the United States - you wouldn't likely need anything that elaborate.

**Some Use Case Findings**

> MTOM: Using JAX-WS, you can send binary attachments such as images or files along with web services requests.  With your example of States - you could have a web service that request that sets/updates each a picture of the states state bird and a base64 encoded audio file of the state song - the picture and song could be MTOM attachments.
>
> AddressingFeature: This looks like it's just used when either the web service or web service client need to use WS-Addressing.  I'd imagine trying to integrate with a third party web service that requires the use of WS-Addressing in which case your client you write would need to specify it's use
>
> RespectBindingFeature: You can use the RespectBindingFeature to control whether a JAX-WS implementation is required to respect the contents of a Web Services Description Language (WSDL) binding that is associated with an endpoint.  By implementing the feature, RespectBindingFeature, you have specified to enforce adherence of the contents of a WSDL binding that is associated with an endpoint for your JAX-WS application.  The actual enforcement of the use of the WSDL document specifications, when they are provided, at run time has not been well defined in versions of the JAX-WS specification previous to Version 2.1.
>
> WebServiceFeature: this is the parent class for the other features.  The use case I imagine would only be the facts that the sub-classes inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks. I know the basics of web services but I have come across a code that uses these classes. So I am trying to learn the concept building a simplest use case.

Comment: Let me see if I can dig around a little more for reasons you'd want to use them then!

Comment: Thank you very much for accepting the answer and marking it as helpful Ofortuna!  Nice to meet you, happy coding!